# Getting \emph back to normal after loading ulem

Tags: text-decorations, emphasis, ulem

I'm typesetting a manuscript that is required to turn all `\emph` into underlines. But then I want to use the original definition of `\emph` for the list of references. How do I get `\emph` to behave like normal again?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Another solution found in the [manual](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ulem/ulem.pdf) is to use the `\usepackage` option `[normalem]`, i.e., `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`. This is probably a better solution if you are using the package `ulem` just for line struck through word or some other feature, but want to use `\emph` as italics. I know this is not exactly your case, but may be useful for someone else.

Comment: There is a huge benefit from using this approach. Without [normalem], each \emph appears as underlined non-italic text. This one preserves emph. +1

Answer (score 44):

Declare `\normalem` at the appropriate point in the document body. (The correspondent macro to switch to "underlined" emphasis is `\ULforem`.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ulem}

\begin{document}

Some \emph{emphasised} text.

\normalem

Some \emph{emphasised} text.

\ULforem

Some \emph{emphasised} text.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I found @Vinicius dos Santos' approach more appropriate.