# Using ulem package changes the style of my reference

Tags: appendices, ulem

I used this `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}` in order to put underline in my file and the next thing I notice is that my reference are all messed up. Here is how I used my reference:

```
\include{Appendix}
\appendix
\renewcommand{\appendixname}{Appendix A}
\renewcommand{\thesection}{A.\arabic{section}}
```

I found that all the font and the styles of the reference are no longer the same as before. Then I tried to put a `\mbox` in front of my `\cite{}`; it still does not solve the problem. Does anyone experience something similar?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx, you can mark code blocks with the `{}`  button (or just indent by 4 spaces) and inline code using back ticks, see my edit. It always helps if you post a complete small document that shows the problem rather than fragments.

Comment: Your question asks about `ulem` and `\cite` but the code section you show uses neither so it is not at all clear how it relates to the question. Defining `\appendixname` as `Appendix A` is wrong (the number or letter should be handled by the counter) but it is unlikely to be the cause of the problem described.

Comment: Since you haven't responded to comments I've suggested to close this question.

Comment: See also, [text decorations - Getting \emph back to normal after loading ulem - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104058/getting-emph-back-to-normal-after-loading-ulem)

Answer (score 24):

Package `ulem` redefines `\em`/`\emph`. Emphasized text is no longer in italics, but the text is underlined. This can be turned off by option `normalem`:

```
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
```

Comment: You made my day - fantastic.