# \usepackage{ulem} package for strikethrough generates underlined reference section

Tags: back-referencing, ulem

I am using the `ulem` package for strikethrough as: 
`\sout{and PET} method`

But this underlines some parts of my references in bibliography section.
If I comment the ulem out then strikethrough goes with it but the underlines in references also go with it.
I want to use strikethrough wo underlining the references, any idea how to do that?

Reference section I am using is pretty standard codes:

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr} %abbrv %apalike %ieeetr
\bibliography{references}
```

Comment: see the second paragraph in the ulem documentation.

Comment: [appendices - Using ulem package changes the style of my reference - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/117347/using-ulem-package-changes-the-style-of-my-reference) and the linked question.