# Conditions in algorithms are underlined

Tags: formatting, incompatibility, algorithm2e, ulem

I'm using algorithm2e for typesetting pseudocode. Generally I find it easy to use, however, I cannot seem to find the setting that underlines the conditions in my while and for loops and if-statements.

```
\begin{algorithm}[H]
\LinesNumbered
\SetAlgoNoLine
\DontPrintSemicolon
\KwData{New relation $m_i(r_{new})m_j$}
\KwResult{An updated network where consequences of the new relation is inferred.}
\BlankLine
Add $(i,j)$ to Q\;
\While{Q is not empty} {

  (i, j) $\leftarrow$ Q.dequeue\;

  \For{k $\leftarrow$ 0 $\KwTo$ n} {
    $m_k(r_{new})m_j$ $\leftarrow$ $m_k(r)m_j \cup (m_k(r)m_i \circ m_i(r_{new})m_j)$\;
    \If {$m_k(r_{new})m_j \subset m_k(r)m_j$} {
      Q.enqueue($(k,j)$)\;
    }
  }

  \For{k $\leftarrow$ 0 $\KwTo$ n} {
    $m_i(r_{new})m_k$ $\leftarrow$ $m_i(r)m_k \cup (m_i(r_{new})m_j \circ m_j(r)m_k)$\;
    \If {$m_i(r_{new})m_k \subset m_i(r)m_k$} {
      Q.enqueue($(i,k)$)\;
    }
  }
}
\caption{Allen's Path Consistency}
\end{algorithm}
```

Which produces this result:

[image]

Basically, I want to disable the underlining of the conditions. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You have to give us a compilable but minimal document which results just in the screenshot above. When I compile your document inside a `\documentclass{article}\usepackage{algorithm2e}\begin{document}...\end{document}`, it does not show that lines. Therefore, I can't reproduce your error.

Comment: Please post a complete [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that), starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`, as I cannot reproduce your error. In the meantime, maybe [Algorithm2e - Permanent fix for no italics if-clause](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/110674/algorithm2e-permanent-fix-for-no-italics-if-clause) is worth looking at.

Comment: Thanks for the nice welcome! That is exactly what I feared - that one of my other dependencies and/or definitions was 'intruding' here. Will update question with MWE soon.

Comment: Tried removing packages from my original in a MWE one by one. Found the suspect - the ``ulem`` package. Answered my question for later reference.

Answer (score 7):

Actually, you don't have to remove the `ulem` package, since it could be useful somewhere else. Use the `\normalem` and `\ULforem` commands provided by the `ulem` package.

The conditions of `algorithm2e` package are *emphasized*, and `ulem` package **by default** replaces italics with underlining for **all** emphasized text, that's why underlines appear automatically when using `algorithm2e` and `ulem` package together.

But fortunately `ulem` package provides a `\normalem` command/option to disable this default feature, and provides a `\ULforem` command/option to enable it. So here is my solution:

```
\normalem %%%% disable auto underline

\begin{algorithm}[H]
    algorithms goes here ...
\end{algorithm}[H]

\ULforem %%%% enable auto underline
```

Reference:

`ulem` manual http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/ulem/ulem.pdf

and this similar example: [Getting \emph back to normal after loading ulem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/104058/getting-emph-back-to-normal-after-loading-ulem)

Answer (score 3):

It appeared that removing the `ulem` package, which I once used for strikeouts, did the trick. It now typesets with the expected format.

Comment: Glad, you found the error and thanks for answering here. But as this is very localized and may not help others in future, you might delete this post. Or, even better, you clarify your question (complete MWE, tag `ulem`) and write a complete answer. If you think, this could help other TeXnicans, this would be the propper way to go. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks for this "localized" yet very useful answer! I have to say, sometimes just one keyword (`ulem`) with a bit of search can solve the problem! I encountered the same problem, and I did find the `ulem` package used in my `.cls` file.

Comment: One should load `ulem` (if really necessary) with the option `normalem`, that is, `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`, so the package will not redefine `\em` and `\emph`.