# Remove underline in Biblatex style angew-chem

Tags: biblatex, underline, biblatex-chem

I'm currently using the Biblatex style angew-chem and if i try to print the bibliography, it always underlines the Title of books. I already went through the .bbx and .cbx files but couldn't find anything like \uline or \underline. [chem-angew .bbx and .cbx](https://github.com/josephwright/biblatex-chem)
[image]
I'm pretty inexperienced in Latex and i feel a little overwhelmed by the code behind chem-angew. Is there any way, to remove this underlining?

Comment: You are loading something that redefines `\emph`: without a full example, I'm guessing `soul`.

Comment: You're loading `ulem` which turns `\emph` into underlining. This underlining cannot break in a `biblatex` context. Most likely you don't want `\emph` to underline, so load `ulem` with the `normalem` option or drop the package altogether. See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488975/35864.

Comment: Any news here? Did you find the culprit? If not, can you produce a small example document that reproduces the issue?

Comment: I voted to close this question as a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488975/35864 as that is the most likely explanation in absence of an example document that reproduces the issue. If the problem persists even when the solutions from the linked questions are applied, please edit your question to include an example document that reproduces your problem. I will then happily vote to reopen.