# Wrapping of Reference

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, apa-style

Could someone help me  -whe nusing biblatex with the apa style and the biber backend,journal names only are not line-wraped according to my document setting (see print screen below):

[image: E.x]

```
\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{american}{american-apa}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\printbibliography
```

Could you help me? It is very much appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: as always please don't post sniplets that no-one understand the context of. Post full but minimal examples that illustrate your problem. The example should be written in such a way that others can copy and test is as is

Comment: Possibly you have `\usepackage{ulem}` in your preamble, if so then change that into `\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}`. Or put `\normalem` before `\begin{document}`.

Comment: See for example https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/488975/35864

Comment: Thanks a lot Marijn - that was the solution !

Comment: @JoeBu ok, let's close as a duplicate then.